# Thread safe in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety

In an ASP.NET MVC, when the application start, I need to some connections (LDAP, …) in background.  Is there a way to do this “thread safe” in a ASP.NET MVC application ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [avoid running background tasks](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) in AS.NET. But if for some reason you need to do it, you could start a new thread in `Application_Start` and perform those tasks. Since `Application_Start` executes only once, this thread will run once (unless of course you configure some timer -> which you probably should not be doing).

If on the other hand you need to consume the work done in this background thread from your ASP.NET MVC controllers (which run inside the context of an HTTP request) you will need proper synchronization in order to ensure that the initialization thread you started in `Application_Start` has finished. Depending on your exact scenario there might be different ways to achieve that.

Comment: If the action take 1min, the application is stuck 1 min in Application_Start ? I'd like avoid this

Comment: In this case you could fire a new thread and perform this task inside the thread. But as I said, if you need to consume the results of this background thread inside your controllers you will have a problem and you will need to synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample how you need to do it, basically we are creating an anonymous `delegate` which will `Invoke` the function that initiates the connections.

```
if(this.InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker( () => yourFunctionThatCreatesSomeConnections(Args)));
}
else
{
yourFunctionThatCreatesSomeConnections(Args);
}
```

Comment: He is asking about ASP.NET, not WinForms or WPF. There's no `InvokeRequired` nor `Invoke` methods.

Comment: I don't see what this link has to do with the `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` methods that you have shown in your answer.

Comment: I did realized that I answered the question wrong and was pointing so some information that is more relevent to the question.